# 'cp' skips some of Eclipse's dot directories 

Tags: cygwin, eclipse

I am trying to backup my Eclipse `.metadata` directory.  The command I run is:

> cp -Rf ~/some/where/.metadata/* ~/some/backup/.metadata/.

The first time I tried this, the copy skipped the lock file and the `.plugins` and `.mylyn` directories.  After doing some research, I found some threads mentioning permission changes.  I applied the changes and found some success.

Now, running the script will not create or traverse into the `.plugins` or `.mylyn` directories.  Additional research has come up with zero results.

I am using:

> Windows XP SP 3
>
> Cygwin 1.7.1-1

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard character `*` in `~/some/where/.metadata/*` does not match files or directories that begin with a dot. This is the behavior of most shells, not just Cygwin. Some alternatives:

- Use another argument to explictly include dot files

```
    cp -Rf ~/some/where/.metadata/* ~/some/where/.metadata/.* ~/some/backup/.metadata/.
```

(`.*` does match files and directories that begin with two or more dots)

- Use an expression that doesn't use the wildcard:

```
    cp -Rf ~/some/where/.metadata/ ~/some/backup/
```

- Use the `tar cf - | tar xf -` idiom

```
    tar cf - ~/some/where/.metadata | (cd ~/some/backup/.metadata ; tar xf -)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `rsync` or `cpio` to copy directories:

```
rsync -acv --delete . DST

find . | cpio -pudvm DST
```

I suspect I'm one of the few people to use `cpio`; it's an old habit from working on SysV machines. It has the drawback that you have to copy from the current directory: if you pass an absolute path to `find`, that path will be replicated in the destination directory. On the other hand `rsync` has its own weirdness depending on whether the SRC directory has a trailing slash.